# I am not able to do any operation when clicked on any item in my listview

Tags: android, listview, adapter

This is my main file . Here I am setting a onClickListener on Listview, which results in any operation
public class Attendance extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ArrayList<attendance_pojo> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private Attendance_adaptwr adapter;
private  int present,absent,datecntr,presents,absents;
private  String year,month,date;
ListView listview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendance);
    init();
    fetchData();
    adapter = new Attendance_adaptwr(this, R.layout.card_attendance, arrayList);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(Attendance.this, "Hello from ROy "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

And Arrayadapter file is here

```
public class Attendance_adaptwr  extends ArrayAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private int layres;
    private ArrayList<attendance_pojo> arrayList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;


    public Attendance_adaptwr(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<attendance_pojo> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.layres = resource;

        this.arrayList = objects;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(layres, null);
        TextView month, workdays;
        Button present,absent;
        month= view.findViewById(R.id.tv_month);
        workdays= view.findViewById(R.id.work_Days);
        present = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_present);
        absent= view.findViewById(R.id.tv_absent);

        attendance_pojo pojo= arrayList.get(position);
        String months= pojo.getMonth();
        Log.d("months",months);
        months= checkmonth(months);
        Log.d("datess",""+pojo.getDate());
        month.setText(months+" "+pojo.getYear());
        workdays.setText(""+pojo.getDatecounter());
        present.setText("Present "+pojo.getPresent());
        absent.setText("Absent "+pojo.getAbsent());
        return  view;
    }


    private String checkmonth(String month) {
        String monthString;
        switch (month) {
            case "1":  monthString = "January";       break;
            case "2":  monthString = "February";      break;
            case "3":  monthString = "March";         break;
            case "4":  monthString = "April";         break;
            case "5":  monthString = "May";           break;
            case "6":  monthString = "June";          break;
            case "7":  monthString = "July";          break;
            case "8":  monthString = "August";        break;
            case "9":  monthString = "September";     break;
            case "10": monthString = "October";       break;
            case "11": monthString = "November";      break;
            case "12": monthString = "December";      break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid month"; break;
        }
        return  monthString;

    }

    }
```

I just cant get any toast when clicked and any Intent is also not fired. I want to make sure that, it should return me position also.

Here is my Layout Code which I have inflated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_margin="10dp">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#9714b3cf"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_month"
            android:background="#b51992b7"
            android:text="January 2017"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="WORK DAYS"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/work_Days"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="18"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="45sp"

            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tv_present"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="#d3edfd07"
                android:text="PRESENT 18"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tv_absent"
                android:text="ABSENT 0"
                android:background="#90e775d2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I had viewed many suggestions , and they almost have same code implemented, but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: post your layout code which you were inflated : 'layres'

Comment: I had added the layout file.. now what next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a row item of listView contains focusable view then OnItemClickListener won't work. Add following attribute to your root layout of list view's item.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

This comes with a consequence that it will no longer allow you to focus on the inner button with hardware buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using buttons in list item, that's why OnItemClick not working

**you need to do 2 steps in your listview_item.xml**

1. set the root layout with: `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`
2. set any focusable or clickable view in this item with:
   `android:clickable="false"` 
   `android:focusable="false"`
   `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`

try to add this three line in your button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width=""
    android:layout_height=""
   //...........Add this three line in your every button................
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    />
```